# How to download all the code to local system?

Tags: upload, backup

I have been creating a lightning app for 3 months and I have completed it. I wrote all my code in the Salesforce Developer Console. So, my question is, is there **any simple way to get all those codes** (aura components, controller classes, helper classes, apex classes, visualforce pages, REST classes) and **download to my local computer** or is there any way to **upload all codes to GitHub or something**?

Comment: Personally I would a) never develop directly against an org - the risk of losing code or metadata is too great, since there's no version control; b) use sfdx development - this gives reasonable SDLC support; c) work locally and push to the org, rather than work on the org and pull - I have seen too many issues with pull bringing stuff I didn't want down and then messing up the tracking state for the org; d) use git from the start of development.

Answer (score 2):

That's really a broad question asking for a simple answer. Visual Studio Code and SFDX CLI have easier ways to retrieve code/ components from your org to the local directory. After you download the required metadata into a local directory, you can put it into GITHub or any version control system of your choice. Get yourself introduced to the basics of [Visual Studio Code](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quickstart-vscode-salesforce) and [SFDX CLI](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quick-start-salesforce-dx?trail_id=sfdx_get_started). Reference to SFDX CLI source pull or retrieve commands can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.224.0.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm#cli_reference_retrieve).

VS Code also comes with an org browser from where you can retrieve individual code/ component or a bulk of them. See screenshot below:

[image]

And there is also another way to create a `package.xml` to list down all that you need to retrieve and use either *ANT* or *SFDX CLI*.

Comment: I followed the `package.xml` method using this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=9062I000000R1mRQAS). Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier you could use the workbench to retrieve the lightning components using the above package.xml, you could follow the below path.

> > create a file in notepad and save it as package.xml in the local storage.

> > https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php

> > from above navigation button hover on to migration then choose retrieve.

> > Choose the above-created package.xml and now click on the retrieve.

You should be able to download the components as a zip file.

You could also use salesforce cli for this purpose.

Additionally, I would suggest you check this particular trailhead module, for better understanding of metadata API:

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/package-xml